# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletRegistration when using OmniFaces library on Glassfish v2.1

Tags: jsf, glassfish, omnifaces

I'm trying to use the excellent OmniFaces library on a Glassfish v2.1 server.

It works well until I try to use the org.omnifaces.util.Faces class. In this case, I encounter a

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletRegistration`

From what I've gathered, it seems this class appeared with the Servlet 3.0 specification.
Glassfish v2.1 is only Servlet 2.5 compatible but OmniFaces documentation indicates that it only requires Servlet 2.5.

Is there something I'm missing ? Is this a dependency that was accidentally added ?

Full configuration is :

- Myfaces 2.1.12
- Glassfish v2.1.1 (9.1_02 Patch12)
- OmniFaces 1.6

Thank you for your answers.

I've come across [this article](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Java-EE-5-and-6-compatibility) that explains things a bit more but I'm still confused as to whether or not it should work on Glassfish 2.1.

Comment: OmniFaces requires Java EE 6 but Glassfish 2 is only EE 5.

Comment: Try current 1.8 snapshot and let me know: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.8-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: 1.8 SNAPSHOT works like a charm. Thank you very much @BalusC for your quick support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OmniFaces is indeed supposed to be Servlet 2.5 compatible, but that's not thoroughly tested as the development and showcase environments are Servlet 3.0 based. See also https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Java-EE-5-and-6-compatibility, so it may happen that something accidently slipped through. This is one of those things.

As per [issue 298](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=298), this has been fixed for the current 1.8 snapshot.